# Using high voltage with nested directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, url-routing, high-voltage

I have a rails 3.2 application in which I am using the gem [High Voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) for my public pages. It seems to work fine, however, I would like to be able to put some subdirectories in my pages folder.

For example:

```
/pages
--/directory_1
----index.html.erb
--/directory_2
----index.html.erb
```

In this example, I want to point my browser to `pages/directory_1/index`, etc. The documentation claims it to be possible:

> You can nest pages in a directory structure, if that makes sense from a URL perspective for you:
>
> link_to "Q4 Reports", page_path("about/corporate/policies/HR/en_US/biz/sales/Quarter-Four")

But something like that doesn't work for me.

I have tried it with a namespace:

```
namespace :directory_1 do
  match "pages/:id" => "high_voltage/pages#show"
end
```

but that of course then goes to `directory_1/high_voltage/pages#show`, which is wrong.

Simply doing match `"pages/directory_1/:id" => "high_voltage/pages#show"` comes with two problems: It does not allow for any views in the pages directory itself anymore, and views with the same filename in different subdirectories will get confused.

So how can I accomplish nested directories inside my pages directory with High Voltage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a directory structure inside `app/views/pages` to reflect the URL hierarchy that you need.

For instance, if you created a view named `about.html.erb` with the path `app/views/pages/about_me/about.html.erb`, you will reference it by using

```
<%= link_to "About", page_path("about_me/about") %>
```

I got this exact solution working in a current project.

Comment: Thanks depa! This is really interesting - I have tried it in a new app and there it works just fine. But not in an older one - I guess I have to find out that one for myself. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, maybe you have an older version of the gem or something?

Comment: No, it's both 1.2.1 - Also, I have nothing in the routes that could override the behavior somehow... Strange!

Comment: Do you have anything in `config/initializers/high_voltage.rb` in your older app?

Comment: No - in fact, I don't have that file. On the contrary, maybe I *should* have something in it?

Comment: No, that shouldn't be the problem. High Voltage doesn't install an initializer by default.